# Maximum number of electron

Tags: physical-chemistry

How many electrons can fit in the orbital for which n = 3 and l = 1?
It is a NEET question which was asked in 2016.
And according to me answer should be 6 electron because maximum number of electron that p orbital can accommodate is 6 but the answer given is 2 electron.
Please explain how it is possible

Comment: It would be 2 electrons for l = 0.

Comment: Read the question carefully!!

Comment: Pay attention to "orbital" vs "subshell" vs. "shell".

Answer (score 2):

It was just a word play.  In question they have used the word orbital.  It means they are asking for maximum no.  of electron in single orbital. The answer would have been 6 electron if it is "orbitals"  in place of "orbital".